# How do I import one class out of a file with many classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, import, classnotfoundexception

I'm confused with the syntaxes:

```
import module.package
from module import package
```

Does the from reference another folder or should I use it for one class out of many in the same file?

Answer (score 6):

A package is any directory that contains a file in the uppermost level named `__init__.py`. A module is any Python file with a `.py` extension.

From those definitions, you can probably figure out that modules can't contain packages. It's the other way around; Packages contain modules. The only thing modules can contain is names which bind to Python objects (classes, functions, etc.)

When you import a package, you simply execute the `__init__.py` file. When you import a module, you simply execute the module file itself. When you import a module from a package using something like `from package import module` or `import package.module`, you execute both `__init__.py` from the package, and the module file itself.

To import only a class from a module, you must use the `from X import Y` statement, where X is `[package1.[subpackage2.]]modulename` and `Y` is the name binded to the object you're importing to the names. Note that even when you do this kind of import, `__init__.py` and the whole module script will still get executed. The only difference is what gets added to your namespace, which is just the object pointed to by `Y`.

Note that the `from X import Y` statement is kind of weird. Because if `X` refers to a package, then `Y` can refer to a module within the package. To overcome this confusion, it's best to think of packages and modules as being namespaces. The biggest difference is that packages are namespaces for modules and modules are namespaces for concrete Python objects.

It's good to note that you can import multiple names from one namespace using commas:

`from collections import OrderedDict, Counter`

And additionally, you can import *all* names from a namespace:

`from itertools import *`

However, this is not recommended because it needlessly pollutes the namespace. For the Python standard library, it's mostly okay, since you're unlikely to have name collisions with things like `takewhile`, but if you are working on a larger project with multiple libraries, it's good to keep your namespace as clean as possible to avoid collisions.

Comment: This is an absolutely great answer! Very clear! I was trying to import a class from a module in a package and was unable to do it. Thanks!